Curl is returning response but Laravel Http client is not returnig respose
-> The below code is based on php Curl.
$curl = curl_init();
// API Endpoint
$url = 'https://api.bybit.com/fht/compliance/tax/v3/private/registertime';

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'X-BAPI-SIGN: ' . $sign,
    'X-BAPI-API-KEY: ' . $apikey,
    'X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP: ' . $timestamp,
    'X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW: ' . $recvWindow,
    'X-BAPI-SIGN-TYPE: 2', 
    'Content-Type: application/json'
),
));

// Execute cURL request and fetch response
$response = curl_exec($curl);

-> The below code is based on Laravel Http Client method
$response = Http::withHeaders(array(
    'X-BAPI-SIGN' => $sign,
    'X-BAPI-API-KEY' => $apikey,
    'X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP' => $timestamp,
    'X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW' => $recvWindow,
    'X-BAPI-SIGN-TYPE' => '2',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
))->post('https://api.bybit.com/fht/compliance/tax/v3/private/registertime');
dd($response->json());

Note: Other paramter which is passing in both curl and http client which is same but we are not getting response in http client.
Successfully response from curl is
{"retCode":0,"retMsg":"","result":{"registerTime":"1562630400"},"retExtInfo":{},"time":1732258576995}

Error response from http client is
array:5 [
  "retCode" => 10004
  "retMsg" => "error sign! origin_string[1732259721000OXG2zzIOaiymlOWj0B5000[]]"
  "result" => []
  "retExtInfo" => []
  "time" => 1732259721441
]

--> Can you please help me to get out this error.
public function bybit_taxPrivateRegisterTime(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $apikey = $request->input('apikey');
            $apisecret = $request->input('apisecret');
            $recvWindow = '5000';
            $timestamp = time() * 1000; // Use time in milliseconds

            // Correctly build the signString (timestamp + apiKey + recvWindow) as in the cURL example
            $signString = $timestamp . $apikey . $recvWindow;

            // Generate signature using HMAC SHA256
            $sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $signString, $apisecret);

            // Headers with proper order
            $headers = [
                'X-BAPI-SIGN' => $sign,
                'X-BAPI-API-KEY' => $apikey,
                'X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP' => $timestamp,
                'X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW' => $recvWindow,
                'X-BAPI-SIGN-TYPE' => '2',  // This can be '2' or another value depending on the Bybit API version
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',  // Ensure the request is sent as JSON
            ];

            // Make the request with headers
            $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)
                            ->post('https://api.bybit.com/fht/compliance/tax/v3/private/registertime');

            $curl = curl_init();
            // API Endpoint
            $url = 'https://api.bybit.com/fht/compliance/tax/v3/private/registertime';

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'X-BAPI-SIGN: ' . $sign,
                    'X-BAPI-API-KEY: ' . $apikey,
                    'X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP: ' . $timestamp,
                    'X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW: ' . $recvWindow,
                    'X-BAPI-SIGN-TYPE: 2', 
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                ),
            ));

            // Execute cURL request and fetch response
            $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
            dd($response->json(), $curl_response);

            return response()->json($response->json());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'API request failed',
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
    }

The below is function and output is given below
array:5 [
  "retCode" => 10004
  "retMsg" => "error sign! origin_string[1732260150000OXG2zzIOaiymlOWj0B5000[]]"
  "result" => []
  "retExtInfo" => []
  "time" => 1732260150743
]

{"retCode":0,"retMsg":"","result":{"registerTime":"1562630400"},"retExtInfo":{},"time":1732260150914}


If the result of curl differs from the http client you are using - then the calls are not equivalent. You may need to debug the http client source to identify the difference. Support for the api you are using or questions like this may help you. It would help you and readers to focus the question on the api-specific error (error sign! origin_string…) this does not come from curl.

Have you ensured that all the header parameters are matching in the two cases and that the timestamp is accurate and not distorted by timezones?
